# Doosan Timeout: connect timed out: 192.168.137.100:12345

Tags: ros

When I run the command:

```
dsr_launcher dsr_moveit.launch model:=m0609 mode:=virtual color:=blue
```

An error occurred: `Timeout: connect timed out: 192.168.137.100:12345`
Previously I connected successfully but the next day I got this error.

How to resolve this error?